# include date in python history file

Tags: python

Ok, I have found to save command lines in interactive python. For instance, I have a .pythonhistory with

```
t=[1,(2,3)]
type(t)
print('Hello');
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to add the date before/in front of the saved commands, in the same way as it can be done with bash commands and the history command

```
1338  18/11/15 15:35:14 cat .python_history
1340  18/11/15 15:36:37 history
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use stuff like IPython or Bpython to get such features